# How to install pysaxon using pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, xslt-2.0, saxon

I try to install library into my project using next way:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

My requirements.txt contains:

```
six
Cython
git+https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon.git
```

But installations fails:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon.git (from -r /var/www/gost/gost/requirements.txt (line 20))
  Cloning https://github.com/ajelenak/pysaxon.git to /tmp/pip-zkz6pq1u-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-zkz6pq1u-build/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Which part of "No module named 'Cython'" seems unclear?  The pip3 utility appears not to know any module named Cython, but 'cython' is listed in your requirements.txt.  Should pip3 know about Cython?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen I tried to use `Cython` name, but the error still occurs

Comment: I repeat my question:  what part of the error message you're getting seems unclear?  And I'll add another question:  Are you sure this is a question about XSLT and Saxon and not a question about pip3?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen, I dont understand last line `ImportError: No module named 'Cython'`. Why Cython cant be found if it contains in requirements. Thanks, I has added tag pip.